# Xcode > UITextView highlights both phone number and email link on 1st 'links' selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uitextview

I've set a the UITextView text to be:

```
@"Test \nTest line 1, \nTest line 2, \nTest line 3, \nArea POST CODE \ntel: +440000000000 \nemail: info@test.com"
```

which loads fine. My problem is that when I select the phone number on the device, both the phone number and email link highlight (see photo).

If I add 3 line breaks, this solves the issue, but this isn't an ideal solution.

I've also tried this in the simulator incase it was just me accidentally pushing both links with my finger, but this isn't the case.

The number is still called correctly and the app works fine, it's just not ideal that it looks like an error.

I can't post images so this is a link to what it looks like:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/do9ls7.jpg

Comment: Did you work this out? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: No solution I'm afraid.